# Dropdown menu disappears when moving cursor from primary menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on a dropdown menu for a site with a fairly large header.  Inside of the header is a `<ul>` containing the primary menu, with each menu item revealing a dropdown.  The problem I am having is that the primary menu is shorter than the header, so there is a small space the cursor has to travel through where it is not hovering over the primary menu or the dropdown.  In this brief space, the dropdown menu disappears.  How can I keep this from happening?  I cannot move the dropdown up, or it overlaps with the header.  I also have been unable to change the height of the `<ul>` in an effective way.

The site is private, but I have created a jsfiddle displaying the problem I'm having: https://jsfiddle.net/x0hvdaqn/

**Edit**
I had made the fiddle with a div instead of a ul for simplicity's sake, but when I changed it to a ul it started working.  The actual menu I am building is made the same way, but does not work.  Why would this be the case?

New fiddle with ul instead of div: https://jsfiddle.net/tgqof8my/

Comment: I can not see the ul tag in your jsfiddle. and please explain your problem according to your example

Comment: I would not recommend to use this approach. What I would do is just increase the height of `#drop` to be the same height as the navigation menu. Open the dropdown just right below that. Enforce the functionality with a little javascript. When you leave button or dropdown divs close the dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

use this code. I hope, you need descreasing your margin in `drop`. Use this...

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
#button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 25%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 25px;
  position: absolute;
}
#drop {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#button:hover #drop {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="button">
  Primary Menu Item
    <div id="drop">
    Dropdown
    </div>
  </div>
  Header
</div>
```

Comment: I need the menu to be flush with the bottom of the header (id="wrapper")